# Deserialize json dictionary to c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm getting this json from an API.

```
string json = "{'serviceSession':{ '123123123':[{'apn':'abc'},{'apn':'bcd'},{'apn':'def'}]}}";
```

When I'm trying to deserialize it with

```
public class ServiceSession
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<ServiceSessionType>> ServiceSessions { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceSessionType
{
    public string Apn { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceSession> (json);
```

I'm getting null.

What's wrong? any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The c# data structure does not match the json data structure. Either change the way the json is composed, or change the class structure in c#.

Comment: Your model doesn't match your JSON.  `123123123` is an array of objects, not a dictionary.  Even if it were a dictionary (which it most definately is not) it would still blow up because you would have duplicate keys.

Comment: `ServiceSessions` is not the same as `serviceSession`

Comment: @SamAxe `123123123` is the key in the dictionary :)

Comment: @zaitsman: oh man.  totally misread that one didnt I :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a missmatch between the datastructure and the json string. You need to change:

```
public class ServiceSession
{
    //ServiceSessions replaced by serviceSession 
    public Dictionary<string, List<ServiceSessionType>> serviceSession { get; set; }
}
```

Another solution is to add a `DataMember` attribute which tells the deserializer the name.

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class ServiceSession
{         
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "serviceSession")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<ServiceSessionType>> ServiceSessions { get; set; }
}
```

This makes sense if you can't change the class or the name is a keyword in C#.