# How can i deserialize json list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have downloaded my json array , but having problem while adding the elements in list in unity.

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = wc.DownloadString("https://pirate-bubble- 
          shooterd02ed.firebaseio.com/Level2.json");

     //It gives me following array 
 {"test1":{"userName":"test1","userScore":81},"test2":{"userName":"test2","userScore":81},"test3": 
 {"userName":"test3","userScore":6},"test4":{"userName":"test4","userScore":6}}

        RootObject  items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
//Root object items are null 
    }

public class RootObject
 {
   public List<user> users{ get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: There's no array in that JSON.

Comment: I am stuck with this, need to add this data in my list. any other option?

Comment: Deserialize it to a dictionary. There are dozens of posts on here about that. Trying to find a useful one to flag this as a duplicate...

Comment: what library do you use for json?

Comment: look at the json you're getting, and determine its _actual_ data structure. seems much more like a `Dictionary<string,user>` to me instead of your RootObject.

Comment: @madreflection is right. The JSON does not represent an array. Array's are surrounded bij [ ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize json dictionary to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128713/deserialize-json-dictionary-to-c-sharp)  Like Franz Gleichmann said, use `Dictionary<string, User>` (with `User` instead of the list in the linked answer). When you're done, you can get a list of the users from the dictionary's `Values` property.

Answer (score 0):

there is no Array in your Downloaded json file from webserver and Why are you deserializing it? you will get perfectly Json object on parsing string JObject.Parse(json).

Comment: I got the objects , but i need to add these in list but it show key and value.